# How to fast fail Jenkins Build Flow Plugin job?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to fail a Build Flow Plugin job if a parameter isn't set. When I try:

```
final parameter = params['PARAMETER']
if (parameter.isEmpty()) {
  out.println('Error: PARAMETER must be defined')
  System.exit(1)
}
```

the entire Jenkins master dies (double plus ungood).

How do I get the job to fail without killing Jenkins?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `Result` on `build.state` then return so as not to execute anything else:

```
import hudson.model.Result

final parameter = params['PARAMETER']
if (parameter.isEmpty()) {
  out.println('Error: PARAMETER must be defined')
  build.state.setResult(Result.FAILURE)
  return
}
```

Comment: The answer is the answer, not additional information.

Comment: The answer I posted is also complete. If it's lacking, feel free to add to it.

Comment: Then please accept it as your answer so that it doesn't appear to be an edit @NoelYap

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to accept for two days. I'll accept it when it allows me to do so.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious to some, but with this solution you also need to put `import hudson.model.Result` at the start of your build flow script. Otherwise, you will get the error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Result for class: Script1`